# How do you write a parameterized test using specs?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs2, parameterized-unit-test

I have several different implementations of a trait that I would like to test, and the test only uses the method signatures of the trait, so it seems like I should be able to use parameterized tests.  However, the specs2 website doesn't seem to describe a straightforward way of writing parameterized tests.  The closest is how to "share examples" but you still need to write every combination of tests and tested code, where I want to be able to specify:

A.  Tests
B.  Classes to test

That can be specified separately, but will test the cartesian product of the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write some thing like:

```
trait TraitTest extends Specification {
    val thingWithTrait: TraitWithVariousImplementations

//TESTS GO HERE

}

class TestFoo extends TraitTest {
    val thingWithTrait = new Foo
}

class TestBar extends TraitTest {
    val thingWithTrait = new Bar
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Also don't forget that you can use for loops:

```
class MySpecification extends mutable.Specification {
  Seq(new Foo, new Bar) foreach { tested => 
    "it should do this" >> { tested must doThis }
    "it should do that" >> { tested must doThat }
  }
}
```